# Why are the hyper links in the html failing to relocate to other pages?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation

Below is an attempt to link pages together using a menu.

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Home</title>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

  <header>

    <article id="logo_section">

      <img src="webpage_logo.png" alt="logo.png">

    </article>

  </header>

  <nav>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

My idea was to link pages together in a navigation bar and a logo.

> All of the HTML pages are within the same folder and they are spelt correctly in the references. I checked.

Comment: maybe `htm` instead of `html` in the filenames?

Comment: The code you posted seems fine, and you can see the links are functional. Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: i don't know how to do that... please educate me thank you

Comment: @ThabisoMotswagole It depends of your browser but for example in Google Chrome you can check it using `F12` key.

Comment: ok thank you very much...

Comment: Have you gotten any .htaccess files changing up on stuff?

Answer (score 0):

First off all, your code for linking has no problems, so everything points at you forgetting to create the files in the same directory, or not creating it at all.
Also, you haven't declared your document (done using  at the top of your page), so the browser will just assume that it is html 4.01, and since  is new in html 5, your nav tag doesn't do anything, I could mention a couple more errors, but you can locate them yourself here: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: i cut out the doctype and they are all in the same folder and all exist

Comment: @ThabisoMotswagole Have you used a web host to get it online, or is it on your own computer?

Comment: i looked but can't find it online... anyway i will ask my lecturer... i will lose a few points but thats ok